# Replace string in a line, where the line is inputed by a variable

Tags: sed

I want to replace a string in a line of a document, with sed. Where the **LINE Number** value should come from a variable, **$var**.

I've tried:

```
sed '%ds/peer/md5/g' $var ./temp.txt
```

but it gives

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `%'
```

Also tried:

```
sed -e '"$var"s/peer/md5/g'-i ./temp.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

Finally tried:

```
printf '%ds/peer/md5/g;\n' 80 | sed -f - ./temp.txt
```

which prints correctly, but I can't save the result file with output redirection (>) or -i command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the correct way is:

```
sed "$var"'s/string1/string2/' -i ./temp.txt
```

where **var** is the variable that have the line number of the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sed -i.bak "s/existing_string/$new_string/g" ./temp.txt`
2. `sed -i.bak "s/$existing_string/new_string/g" ./temp.txt`

Here `$` is used for your variable, in `sed` remember to use `" "` while using variables within it.

The option `-i.bak` will create backup file of original.

Comment: Hi, the variable must be used to the line number, not the string to be replaced, or replacing string.

Comment: OOK, you wanted to replace the string in a particular line!

Comment: yes... where the line is given by a variable.